# Double spaces count towards character limits in comments

Tags: bug, comments, character-limit

If you put a double space in a comment, or any amount of spaces for that matter, it shows up as a single space.  But the spaces still count towards the maximum characters you can put in a comment.  So I often find myself, when in need of an extra 10 characters, going back through all my comments to remove all of those doubel spaces that I instinctively put after a period as I was taught to do way back in elementary school.

Is there any way to not count characters that won't show up anyways towards the maximum character limit?

Comment: @ShadowWizard my problem is the opposite, I think.  It _doesn't_ count towards the minimum, but it _does_ count towards the maximum.

Comment: Same thing: it's misleading due to client side vs. server side validation, which are not the same. The team can fix it once and for all by using server side validation only.

Comment: THEN DON'T DOUBLE SPACE! IT'S WROOONG. Just... no.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't care about it being misleading.  I care about it counting.  But whatever.

Comment: @bjb568 Some habits are hard to break.  And I wouldn't be so quick to call it wrong - the [jury is still out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing) on this one.

Comment: @YEZ HTML strips it, isn't that enough for it to be wrong?

Comment: The count has never been accurate, so why do you expect it do be so now? It doesn’t even know what a character is, and in fact, lies. You do not even have to enter 15 characters: 8 suffices. They also lie about the 600-character max, since in fact, the maximum is only 300 characters.

Comment: ⃠

Comment: @tchrist I don't know why previous inaccuracy should be justification for continuing so.  You could apply that to every bug report.  And you can get away with less than 8 if you really want to.

Comment: @Yez The point is that the evidence on the table is that they really do not care about the accuracy of the reported count.